# If $f(x)$ is a monic polynomial in ${\mathbb Z}[x]$ and all roots have absolute value 1 , then all roots are roots of unity.

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, roots, roots-of-unity

I am trying to understand the statement that was mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2579818/976076).

> If $f(x)$ is a monic polynomial in ${\mathbb Z}[x]$ and all roots have absolute value 1, then all roots are roots of unity.

I was wondering why we need to assume that $f(x)$ is monic. Are there any non-monic polynomials where the conclusion does not hold?

Comment: @ThePhoenix thank you!

Comment: @ThePhoenix That can be an answer, I'd say.

Comment: To give a more theoretical answer, if $f$ is monic it means that its roots are algebraic *integers*, rather than just general algebraic *numbers*. It is not true that an algebraic integer with abs. value 1 is a root of unity, but it *is* true if all the roots of its minimal polynomial have abs. value 1, which is what your assumption implies. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323/are-all-algebraic-integers-with-absolute-value-1-roots-of-unity

Comment: Interestingly enough, a stronger claim is true. If all roots of a monic polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ have absolute value less than or equal to $1$, then all roots are either $0$ or roots of unity. It surprises me that this weaker version of the theorem (the one in the link) is the one I most often see, since most proofs apply to the stonger version just fine.

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:linear-algebra]?

Answer (score 0):

ThePhoenix gives the example $5x^2-6x+5=0$, but $2x^2-3x+2=0$ will do with smaller coefficients. The roots are complex conjugates with the discriminant $-7$, and their product is $2/2=1$ so they must have unit modulus. But the actual roots are given by

$\dfrac{3\pm i\sqrt7}{4},$

and the arguments of these roots are $\pm\cos^{-1}(3/4)$. This can't be a rational multiple of $\pi$ since the cosine is a rational number that isn't half an integer, and roots of unity must have arguments that are rational multiples of $\pi$. $\rightarrow\leftarrow$